# Firebase Dynamic Links does not work if the target app have run

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I setup **Firebase Dynamic Links** in my project. At a glance everything works. But there is one exception. When I click the link my app starts and processes it. But if my app have already run and I click the link the app is appearing on the screen and it doesn't process the link because the intent in the **FirebaseDynamicLinks** listener is null.
I have only one **Activity** with singleTask launchMode and I subscribe for the **FirebaseDynamicLinks** in two places: onCreate() and onNewIntent().
I use the latest version of the library - 19.1.1
Can anybody explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake.
In the `onNewIntent(Intent)` method I used `Activity.getIntent()` instead of incoming parameter.